# What are these metal flaps protruding from my garage’s concrete sidewall?

Tags: concrete, flooring, garage

I'm planning phase to re-finish my concrete garage floor with epoxy. I noticed around the base of the floor there are flaps of what is thin sheet metal painted over by the previous owner.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

What are these flaps and can they be trimmed to be flush with the wall? I’m not sure if they’re something important such as flashing or termite barriers for example.

**UPDATE 10/09/2020:** Added more photos below.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Enough gaps to not stop termites...

Comment: the pictures don't look upright ... please correct the orientation

Comment: Are you sure it's all metal? Some of it looks like plastic vapor barrier coated with floor paint.

Comment: I've uploaded additional photos with ones that were taken at an upright angle.

Comment: @isherwood I inspected the flaps again and as far as I can tell it's all sheet metal. I originally thought it was plastic or some other material due to the paint but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a lead or aluminum damp proof course between the nib wall and the framing.

If that's what it is it can be trimmed, as DPC only needs to be between the concrete and the wood.

Answer (score 1):

That may be (intended as) a termite barrier, and if so you don't want to trim it.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to post that as a comment to Jasen's answer?

Comment: No, I disagree with that answer in the event that termites are the concern - while "damp" may stop at a truncated barrier, termites are adept at bridging across such things, which is why termite shields typically flare out and down - just like these, though they appear to have been dented up quite a bit over time.

Comment: Is it normal to have termite shields inside a garage like this? I think you raise a valid point, as if this is the intention cutting them could be a regrettable mistake assuming the protection they provide in their current state is effective...

Comment: It is a termite barrier, and yes it is typical to place the shield there too. When untreated wood is resting on a concrete wall that is structural, and pressure treated wood is not in use. the barrier is needed.